# How to do validation using useRef()

Tags: reactjs, use-ref

How do I validate input box value using useRef .

Initial validation is not required once user clicks on input box and comes out then it should validate if input box is empty it should show input box cannot be empty.

[Codesandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-rain-fe2rn?file=/src/App.js)

code i tried. using onBlur

```
export default function App() {
  const name = React.useRef("");

  const nameBlurData = (name) => {
    console.log("name", name);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form>
        <input
          onBlur={() => nameBlurData(name.current.value)}
          type="text"
          ref={name}
          placeholder="Enter First Name"
        />

// show error message here
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `ref` here?

Comment: I don't get your question. You'll need some kind of state in order to achieve your desired functionality (i.e. rendering something based on validity of the input), why use `useRef`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use "useRef" to validate the value of an input field.
No need to use "useState".

Below code is a basic implementation of OP's question

You can replace the "console.log" with your alert component.

```js
import { useRef } from "react";

const ComponentA = () => {
   const emailRef = useRef(null);
   const passwordRef = useRef(null);

   const onBlurHandler = (refInput) => {
      if (refInput.current?.value === "") {
         console.log(`${refInput.current.name} is empty!`);
      }  
   }

return (
   <form>
      <input ref={emailRef} onBlur={onBlurHandler.bind(this, emailRef)} />
      <input ref={passwordRef} onBlur={onBlurHandler.bind(this, passwordRef)} /> 
   <form/>
 )
}
```

Link to ["useRef"](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

Note: Not tested, code typed directly to SO's RTE

Comment: I think you meant "onBlur={}"

Answer (score 0):

You can use a local state and conditionally render an error message like this:

```
  const [isValid, setIsValid] = useState(true)

  const nameBlurData = (name) => {
     setIsValid(!!name);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form>
        <input
          onBlur={() => nameBlurData(name.current.value)}
          type="text"
          ref={name}
          placeholder="Enter First Name"
        />
        {!isValid && <span> input must not be empty </span> } 
      </form>
```

Note that you don't really need a `ref` in this case, you can just use the event object like:

```
onBlur={(event) => nameBlurData(event.target.value)}
```

[image: Edit vigilant-sun-t7n6v]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `useState` hook to update the value of the `name` property. Using `ref` is not ideal here.

Live demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-apqj86?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/App.js

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [hasError, setError] = useState(false);
  const nameBlurData = () => {
    if (name.trim() === '') {
      setError(true);
      return;
    }
    setError(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form>
        <input
          onBlur={nameBlurData}
          type="text"
          value={name}
          onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="Enter First Name"
        />

        {hasError ? <p style={{ color: 'red' }}>Name is required</p> : null}
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```